# why is my wifi faster when downloading from the internet compared to exchanging files between two windows machine (and one connected via ethernet)

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm using the wifi router provided by my ISP (spectrum.net). When checking internet speed I'm consistently getting 300Mbps download and 40Mbps upload via wifi. The download speed usually increases to 1Gbps when using ethernet. 
Now I wanted to check my wifi speed without any internet in between and I'm consistently getting only 50Mbps (the other windows 10 machine connected via ethernet) -- even when standing next to the wifi router.
I'm curious...

In order to determine the bandwidth I used taskmanager/performance/wifi.

Comment: MB or Mb? Windows shows transfer rates in megabytes per second, not megabits per second. 50MBps is 400 Mbps. Still a discrepancy there. Could be that the hard disk is only capable of sending/receiving data that fast.

Comment: I thought, that I made it clear by using the matching abbreviation for MegaBitsPerSecond -- Mbps

Comment: How fast is the download from your other Windows machine with the wired ethernet? Variables on the wired side include: Network card speed, Cable type, Router/Switch speed, Jumbo Packets?